# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:"_BRANCH_REQUEST_KEY_UPDATE"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, branch.io

I try to Install Branch SDK from NuGet and take error

> 1> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: 1>
>   "_BRANCH_REQUEST_KEY_UPDATE", referenced from: 1> -u command line
>   option 1> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 1> clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation) 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(791,3):
>   error : Native linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _BRANCH_REQUEST_KEY_UPDATE. This symbol was referenced by the managed member IOSNativeBranch.Constants.BRANCH_REQUEST_KEY_UPDATE. Please
>   verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and
>   native libraries linked. 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(791,3):
>   warning : References to 'kernel32' might require additional
>   -framework=XXX or -lXXX instructions to the native linker 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(791,3):
>   error : Native linking failed. Please review the build log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Vatsal from Branch.io.

Can you try setting linker behavior with "Framework SDK's only"? It should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks, it's work for me. However, it dramatically increases build time. Maybe you know any other workaround?